# The package system is broken (with package ethereum-swarm)

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried to update using the update manager and I couldn't because I encountered an error halfway through (error: `brokencount>0`). I have tried `apt-get -f install`, but it doesn't work.

You can check my terminal:

```
trungtin@trungtin-S551LN:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
debugedit libllvm5.0 librpmbuild3 librpmsign3 rpm swarm
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
ethereum-swarm
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5.560 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package ethereum-swarm.
(Reading database ... 316020 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ethereum-swarm_0.3.1+build14601+xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ethereum-swarm (0.3.1+build14601+xenial) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ethereum-swarm_0.3.1+build14601+xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/swarm', which is also in package swarm 2.1.6-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ethereum-swarm_0.3.1+build14601+xenial_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to clean cache then install again or overwrite ethreum-swarm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the ethereum ppa with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ethereum/ethereum` and then had to run `sudo apt-get -f install` as the error message suggested, before any other apt commands would complete. Then I could run `sudo apt-get purge swarm` successfully, and then I could run `sudo apt upgrade`. I couldn't comment on what things are necessary or sufficient, though.

Comment: yup, worked likea charm. I gave up on solidity all together with Ether, a security mess atm, will revisit in the future. Thanks Alex.

Comment: This worked after the update process broke, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Three options here:

- ask package authors about conflict between their `ethereum-swarm` and [ubuntu package `swarm`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=swarm).
- remove standart `swarm` Ubuntu package and then install `ethereum-swarm`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge swarm
  sudo apt-get install ethereum-swarm
  ```
- force installation of `ethereum-swarm` (you take this risk, as this is not recommended):

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i --force-all \
  /var/cache/apt/archives/ethereum-swarm_0.3.1+build14601+xenial_amd64.deb
  ```

  then remove `swarm` package with `sudo apt-get purge swarm` and reinstall `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ethereum-swarm` again (to keep system clean).

Comment: How can I use sudo apt-get purge swarn?

Comment: @TínHuỳnh In current state it may not work, but you can try. Then use third method (with `--force-all`).

Comment: But it takes risk right?

Comment: Usually such method is not recommended. But in current situation it is normal.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get purge swarm` it still gives me the same error;
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ethereum : Depends: ethereum-swarm but it is not going to be installed
`
How can I uninstall swarm?